# Redis iterate over key groups

Tags: redis, jedis

I'm would like to check that all my keys in redis are correct.

I'm storing the keys in groups like so:

```
userid:fname
userid:lname
userid:age
...
```

I would like to iterate over the them by grouping them by userid and then check each group from fname, lname and age.

How can I do this?

Comment: SCAN command is probably what you need

Comment: Can you please jive me an example on how to do this? I'm using Jedis in Java.

Comment: Surely, you can locate the redis command documentation and documentation for jedis?

Comment: This is the project page https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis
It basically have the same function as redis in the Jedis object.

Comment: Hi, I tried using the SCAN command but I cant seem to understand how to use it properly, may you please show me an example?

Comment: Try looking in the tests folder, e.g.: https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/blob/7f45a2ca243db2b704965018b14f04e50ff62d98/src/test/java/redis/clients/jedis/tests/commands/AllKindOfValuesCommandsTest.java#L519

Comment: Your data structure seens odd, shouldn't you use a Hash instead? You would have 1 key per user, and each info (fname, lname, etc) would be fields in your hash.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```java
ScanParams params = new ScanParams();
params.match("userid:fname*");

// Use "0" to do a full iteration of the collection.  
ScanResult<String> scanResult = jedis.scan("0", params);
List<String> keys = scanResult.getResult();
```

Repeat above code for lname and age. Or, match `user:id` and then filter the groups using a regex and iterating through `keys`.

EDIT: For large collections (millions of keys), [a scan result will return a few tens of elements](http://redis.io/commands/scan). Adjust your code accordingly to continue scanning until the whole collection of keys has been scanned:

```java
ScanParams params = new ScanParams();
params.match("userid:fname*");

// An iteration starts at "0": http://redis.io/commands/scan
ScanResult<String> scanResult = jedis.scan("0", params);
List<String> keys = scanResult.getResult();
String nextCursor = scanResult.getStringCursor();
int counter = 0;

while (true) {
    for (String key : keys) {
        addKeyToProperGroup(key);
    }

    // An iteration also ends at "0"
    if (nextCursor.equals("0")) {
        break;
    }

    scanResult = jedis.scan(nextCursor, params);
    nextCursor = scanResult.getStringCursor();
    keys = scanResult.getResult();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Redis based `java.util.Iterator` and `java.lang.Iterable` interfaces offered by [Redisson](https://redisson.org) Redis client.

Here is an example:

```
RedissonClient redissonClient = RedissonClient.create(config);

RKeys keys = redissonClient.getKeys();

// default batch size on each SCAN invocation is 10
for (String key: keys.getKeys()) {
...
}

// default batch size on each SCAN invocation is 250
for (String key: keys.getKeys(250)) {
...
}
```